# how to send files using formData() in an api request using vuejs and axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, form-data

I want to upload a file to the server via an API. On documenter.getpostman, this is how to use the API

```
--form 'type="1"' \
--form 'user_id="1"' \
--form 'file=@"/C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/xxx.postman_collection.json"'
```

This is what I did

```
                try {
                    const fd = new FormData()
                    fd.append('file', this.dropFiles)
                
                    let response = await this.$axios.post('/staff/customer/add/document', {
                        type: this.uploadType,
                        user_id: this.user_id,
                        file: fd,
                    })

                    console.log(response.data.success)    
                }
                catch(err){
                     console.log(err)
                }
```

`this.dropFiles` contains the files from the `input type="file"`, and i'm able to see its contents when I log it to the console, but logging `fd` which carries the form data always returns an empty object. And `type: this.uploadType, user_id: this.user_id` are other params i'm sending to the api

The request always returns 400(bad request)

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js?b50d:54)
```

I'm not sure if the API wants the path to the file, because, I have tried hard coding the file path into the request like this

```
let response = await this.$axios.post('/staff/customer/add/document', {
    type: this.uploadType,
    user_id: this.user_id,
    file: '/home/myDevice/Downloads/download.jpeg',
})
```

but still, get the same response. Please I need all the help i can get, thanks.

Comment: You can not send FormData as a single parameter, in combination with other parameters. (Well, you can, but that won't make sense to the receiver.) You need to append `type` and `user_id` to the FormData object, same as you did with the file, and then send _only_ the plain FormData object.

Comment: @CBroe I have appended both ```type``` and ```user_id``` to the formData just like you said, i'm still getting the same error, and when i use dev tools network to check the payload for the request, the ```file``` is an empty object.

Comment: And did you modify what you are passing as second parameter to the `post` method as well?

Comment: @CBroe this is what i now have  after appending both to ```fd``` 
 ``` let response = await this.$axios.post('/staff/customer/add/document',  {
                        file: fd
                    })
```

Comment: You need to send _only_ the formdata object. Right now, you are still trying to send an object, that contains the formdata object under a property name `file`. `{ file: fd }`-> `fd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this using @CBroe comment.
I appended both `type` and `user_id` into the `formData`, and then passed in `formData` object.

```js
                try {
                    const fd = new FormData()
                    fd.append('file', this.dropFiles)
                    fd.append('type', this.uploadType)
                    fd.append('name', this.fileName)
                    fd.append('user_id', this.user_id)
                
                    let response = await this.$axios.post('/staff/customer/add/document', fd)

                    console.log(response.data.success)    
                }
                catch(err){
                     console.log(err)
                }
```